# Alternative to string_upper/2

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Machine, which my code is supposed to work on, for some reason doesn't know predicate `string_upper/2`. Are there any alternatives? Eventually, what would code for this predicate look like?

Comment: What machine is this? And what Prolog?

Answer (score 0):

Break the string into a list of character codes. Then convert those codes into the appropriate upper case code if necessary before reconstructing the string. A more complete answer would require knowing which prolog you're using, its available predicates & how it represents strings.

---

You might want to read up on different Prolog's handling of characters, Unicode and strings.  For this, the SWI-Prolog implementation has some good documentation:

How traditional(Edinburgh), ISO & SWI prolog handles characters: [4.2 Character Representation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chars)

How ISO & SWI prologs support Unicode [2.16.1.8 Unicode Prolog source](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=unicodesyntax)

How SWI has a specific string-type object which uses quotes to denote them: [5.2 The string type and its double quoted syntax](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=strings)

Comment: My string looks like `a-b`. I am actually not sure if that is a string.

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave in the comments is actually not a string but a pair of atoms. Since you already opted to use `upcase_atom/2`, in the code you deleted from your post, I'd point out that this built-in is only working in one direction, that is if the the first argument is atomic. Consider the following queries:

```
?- upcase_atom(bo,'BO').   % Is 'BO' the uppercase version of bo?
true.                      % Yes, it is.

?- upcase_atom(bo,B).      % What's the uppercase version of bo?
B = 'BO'.                  % It's 'BO'

?- upcase_atom(B,'BO').    % What atom has 'BO' as uppercase version?
ERROR: upcase_atom/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

?- upcase_atom(B,1).       % What atom has 1 as uppercase version?
ERROR: upcase_atom/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Your example query, from your deleted code, is `?- divideIt(a-b).`. The atom `a` is unified with the variable `V` in the head of the rule `divideIt/1`. Then Prolog calls the first goal `upcase_atom(V,ve)` that has to fail because the atom `ve` is not the uppercase version of the atom `a`. Consequently your example query fails as well. If you apply the following minor changes to your predicate, it yields the desired result:

```
divideIt(V-W) :-
   upcase_atom(V,Ve),     % <- Ve (=variable) instead of ve (=atom)
   write(Ve),
   write('-'),            % <- '-' instead of "-"
   upcase_atom(W,We),     % <- We (=variable) instead of we (=atom)
   write(We).

?- divideIt(a-b).
A-B
true.
```